# Http headers to cache files forever until modified

Tags: java, spring, http-caching

I serve files from the filesystem via a Spring `@Controller`, and I want to make the best possible use of the browser cache.

Here is the method handling the request:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/file/{f:.*}")
public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("f") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {

    File file = new File("/folder/" + fileName);

    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", CacheControl.maxAge(7, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePrivate().getHeaderValue());
    response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", file.lastModified());
    response.setHeader("ETag", "" + file.lastModified());

    return new FileSystemResource(file);
}
```

The browser should cache the files forever, except if they were modified on the filesystem since the last request.

I am not sure how to set `Cache-Control` and `Expires`.

How to set them, and which headers would I need to add to get the desired behaviour?

Note that I also use `Spring Security` which adds the following headers by default:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
```

Those headers are fine for "normal" pages, but I dont' want them for the method shown above handling `/file/**`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually ETag header is used for that. From the official Spring documentation on ETags:

> An ETag (entity tag) is an HTTP response header returned by an
> HTTP/1.1 compliant web server used to determine change in content at a
> given URL.

The request headers used with ETags are ["If-None-Match"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.26) and ["If-Match"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.24). Those are used to make requests conditional.

Edit: To get it working with Spring Security you have to disable setting those headers. In configure method you can add `httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl().disable();`